# php search engines

Tags: php, mysql, search

Can anyone help me with a good list of php site search engines. I am thinking of implementing a google site search, but I would rather not pay for that and I would rather have as much control as I can over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read through [Roll your own Search Engine with Zend_Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html).

The article is rather old though, so have a look at the [ZF Reference Guide about Zend_Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html) too. [Searching for Zend Lucene on Google](http://www.google.de/#q=zend+Lucene) should yield plenty useful results too.

Comment: @kalpaitch well, you have to use the `Zend_Lucene` component from the Zend Framework. You do **not** have to use ZF's MVC or other unrelated components. Remember, ZF is a library of loosely coupled components. Those components *can* be used together to form a full stack, but it is perfectly feasible to use them standalone, like you would use a PEAR component for instance. You can use ZF alongside other frameworks if you want, e.g. Symfony or CodeIgniter. It's not's all or nothing with ZF.

Comment: @kalpaitch you're welcome. I remember there have been a number of questions about how to develop with Zend_Lucene on StackOverflow, so you might want to search around here.

Answer (score 0):

[Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/index.html) is pretty good, but it isn't written in PHP. It has got PHP libraries to interface with it though. You could also have a look at [Zend_Search_Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html) from Zend Framework. Both of these make search indexes so you can do fast searches.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Zend Lucene implementation:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html
http://devzone.zend.com/article/91

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pay for Google Site Search and there's a small chance for much control means greater quality of results.

If your site is very specific you need to write you own code for search.

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx is one of the best Open Source Search Engines. It has an excellent PHP API. Has very good community and forum too. PHP API for Sphinx comes embedded with the tar/zip file that you will download and with ease it can be embedded on top of your database. Has great vertical search capabilities. Its pretty simple to implement, try it out.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a new PHP Search engine script, that can be implemented in any website, it is made with PHP 5.4+, MySQL, and Ajax.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/site-search-engine-php-ajax/

It crawls and indexes automatically the site pages, similar to Sphider.
It can uses PDO or MySQLi for connecting to MySQL database.